# cannot set html div width

Tags: html, css

I want to make the form looks 1200px in width. However, when I set width in class .container or .form-group, or even in form tag, it won't work. Only when I set width in textarea tag will it work. What is the problem?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="status-box"></textarea>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You do not have in css link `type="text/css"`

Comment: You only want the `.container` to be 1200px width? In that case your CSS works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/0h5pbaLs/

Comment: @wolfgang1983 that isn't needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your container size is fine - but if you want your elements to fill the container, you'll need to set the width of them seperately.

E.g.

```
.container { width: 1200px; }

textarea, input { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `textarea` fill the `1200px`, just add this line in your CSS code :

```
textarea {width: 100%;}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/06z3u60r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Also provide some height in CSS Class

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
min-height:10px // or Height:whatever the height you prefers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a problem. As you can see the width is already active tho it doesn't show since there is no identification. [snippet here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/vwwxnsox).
If you change your css to look like the following you can see it for yourself.

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color:blue; <-- This will show the full width of your div in a color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that the CSS knows where it's being applied, you should try this in your style file:

```
.container .form-group {
  width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Or if you're tying to size your text area you need to use it's *rows* and *cols* attributes: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: You will use `rows` and `cols` if you need to size the `textarea` based on the font family and font size of the `textarea`, but `cols` is most of the time not that usefull. Using `css` and `width` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "background-color: gray" to your container class. You will see the div width works. The width is for div, while it's not for the content in the div. So the right way is add width to textarea.